# How to write a case insensitive query and only return unique records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4 and PostgreSQL and trying to figure out a way to write a case insensitive query method that returns records such that you get only one of the case insensitive duplicates. For a simple example, suppose you have an `Email` model that represents sent email, and has `id`, `to`, `from`, and your data looks like:

```
id| to              | from
------------------------------------
1 | tester@test.com | sender@test.com
2 | TESTER@TEST.com | sender@test.com
3 | foo@test.com    | sender@test.com
```

and I want the query method to only return:

`[<#Email:0x1234 id: 1, to: "tester@test.com", from: "sender@test.com">, <#Email:0x1224 id: 3, to: "foo@test.com", from: "sender@test.com">]`

So basically I only want one of the records if it turns out to be a match when case is ignored. Is this possible to do in a one-liner and have the database return the right records or is there another clever way of doing this? I am hitting a wall for some reason and would appreciate your help!

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Postgres Window functions. You'll want to look into the `row_number()` function.

Here is how you can achieve your desired result:

```
select id,fro,tos
FROM
(
select id,fro,
tos, row_number() over (partition by LOWER(tos)  ORDER BY LOWER(tos) DESC) AS alpharow
from stacks
) flattened
where alpharow = 1
```

I had to use alternate names for "to" and "from" as those are reserved words - but it should be obvious what they map too in your example.

Some followup readings:

https://buildingvts.com/understanding-postgres-window-functions-697bc0ff2ed4

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/postgres-window-functions